# Ford Focus 2012 central lock problem

Tags: ford, focus, fuse, central-locking

I have a problem with my Ford Focus 2012 with its central lock mechanism. I have replaced the fuses (70,83) but nothing happened. Then I checked all fuses with voltmeter one by one and found that all fuses on the right side (82 to 89) have no power on both sides.

I can hear a very slight noise when I press the unlock button on the key fob, but nothing happens when I press the lock button (only the horn). Also, the central lock button inside the vehicle does not work!

Are there any fuses or relays that should I check?

[image]